# Redirect RuntimeError to log instead of console in wxPython?

Tags: python, redirect, wxpython, runtime-error

How do I redirect `RuntimeError` to log instead of the console?

In the code below, the `'Hello'` is printed to console, which is redirected to the `wx.TextCtrl`. The `RuntimeError` raised OnClose is printed to the terminal however. How do I redirect the `RuntimeError` to see same log as the `'Hello'`?

```
import sys
import wx

class RedirectText:
    def __init__(self, log):
        self.log = log
    def write(self,string):
        self.log.AppendText(string)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        redirection = RedirectText(self.log)
        sys.stdout = redirection
        print 'hello'
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    def OnClose(self, event):
        raise RuntimeError('error')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume you just have to assign your log to sys.stderr.

Comment: Haha! That was waaaay easier than I thought. Silly to have overlooked that little detail.